# Word width before and after multiplication

Tags: c, optimization, long-integer

I can't tell if anyone had asked this question before.  The root behind this question is the mistake (in my opinion) in standard C or C++ in that the implicit word width of an integer product after multiplication is the same as the larger of word widths of the integer multiplier and multiplicand.

So, this wouldn't be a problem if, in C, multiplying an `int32_t` times an `int32_t` would implicitly result in an `int64_t`.  But it doesn't.  Nearly every integer CPU and fixed-point DSP that I am aware of multiplies two N-bit operands into a register (or register pair) that is 2N bits wide and I wish that C would do that (without some kinda inline assembly).

Now I know that this works (it's a simple fixed-point Direct Form 1 biquad filter with fraction saving around the sole point of quantization):

```
int64_t accumulator;

int64_t a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;   /* 2nd-order IIR coefficients */

int32_t state_x1, state_x2, state_y1, state_y2, state_fraction;

int32_t x, y;

int32_t get_input(void);

void put_output(int32_t y);

int i, num_samples;
         /* num_samples is the number of samples per block */

/*  load up your coefficients, cast all to int64_t */

/*  load up your states from wherever */

accumulator = (int64_t)state_fraction;

for (i=0; i<num_samples; i++)
    {
    x = get_input();

    accumulator += b0*x;
    accumulator += b1*state_x1;
    accumulator += b2*state_x2;
    accumulator += a1*state_y1;
    accumulator += a2*state_y2;

    if (accumulator > 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
       {
       accumulator = 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;     /* clip value */
       }
    if (accumulator < -0x2000000000000000)
       {
       accumulator = -0x2000000000000000;    /* clip value */
       }

    y =  (int32_t)(accumulator>>30);   /* always rounding down */

    state_x2 = state_x1;             /* bump the states over */
    state_x1 = x;
    state_y2 = state_y1;
    state_y1 = y;

    accumulator = accumulator & 0x000000003FFFFFFF;
    /* keep the fractional bits that you dropped for the next sample
       otherwise clear the accumulator */

    put_output(y);
    }

state_fraction = (int32_t)accumulator;

/*  save your states back to wherever  */
```

But I don't want to waste the MIPS to multiply an `int64_t` times an `int32_t` when I know that both values are 32-bit numbers.  But I also know that the result ***must*** be 64-bits wide else there is trouble.

Suppose I did this:

```
int64_t accumulator;

int32_t a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;   /* 2nd-order IIR coefficients */

int32_t state_x1, state_x2, state_y1, state_y2, state_fraction;

int32_t x, y;

int32_t get_input(void);

void put_output(int32_t y);

int i, num_samples;
         /* num_samples is the number of samples per block */

/*  load up your coefficients, (leaving as int32_t) */

/*  load up your states from wherever */

accumulator = (int64_t)state_fraction;

for (i=0; i<num_samples; i++)
    {
    x = get_input();

    accumulator += (int64_t)b0*x;
    accumulator += (int64_t)b1*state_x1;
    accumulator += (int64_t)b2*state_x2;
    accumulator += (int64_t)a1*state_y1;
    accumulator += (int64_t)a2*state_y2;

    if (accumulator > 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
       {
       accumulator = 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;     /* clip value */
       }
    if (accumulator < -0x2000000000000000)
       {
       accumulator = -0x2000000000000000;    /* clip value */
       }

    y =  (int32_t)(accumulator>>30);   /* always rounding down */

    state_x2 = state_x1;             /* bump the states over */
    state_x1 = x;
    state_y2 = state_y1;
    state_y1 = y;

    accumulator = accumulator & 0x000000003FFFFFFF;
    /* keep the fractional bits that you dropped for the next sample
       otherwise clear the accumulator */

    put_output(y);
    }

state_fraction = (int32_t)accumulator;

/*  save your states back to wherever  */
```

Would the compiler be smart enough to understand what I want?  To multiply two 32-bit signed integers together and add the 64-bit result into a 64-bit accumulator ***without*** casting anything into a 64-bit register? (i.e. no sign-extension operation and no 64 x 64 bit multiply?)

I wish I could write this is C code without worrying that the ARM compiler will create non-optimal code.  Am I forced to do this in assembly code to make sure it's done right?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple unrelated languages in your questions. Which one are you really programming in?

Comment: It could be either.  I completely disagree with your concern.  It could happen in either a C or C++ context.  And I don't believe that the languages inherently treat this issue differently.  At its core, it's C.  (But to suggest that C and C++ are *"unrelated languages"* is sorta funny.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Try and use a template in C. Then watch what happens with the `auto` keyword. Or the differences in behaviour of `union`s.  And arrays. And those are the non-ideological differences. you *USE* C++ differently than you use C even when the same syntax could work in both languages. This question looks like it avoids most of that nastiness, but that nastiness still exists.

Comment: In the deeply nested loops in C++, where there are no "extensions" or features of C++ that do not exist in C (nothing about objects or methods or even about structs or function calls), I do not expect C++ to do ***anything*** different than C.  This is nothing other than doing integer arithmetic and a little bit-masking in a `for` loop.

Comment: What is "the compiler"? Have you tried looking at the generated output, possibly using different optimization settings? Generally, compilers are bound by the "as-if" rule, which means that they can do anything if there are no observable differences in the output.

Comment: Look at the new `<stdckdint.h>` header in C23 (see N3054 at https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/wg14_document_log.htm, for example).  It defines macros including `ckd_mul(type1 *result, type2 a, type3 b)` which multiplies `a` by `b` in "infinite precision" and assigns that to `*result`, returning either `false` if the multiplication fits or `true` (and if true, the value in `*result` is the mathematical results wrapped the width of `*result`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, this wouldn't be a problem if, in C, multiplying an `int32_t` times an `int32_t` would implicitly result in an `int64_t`. But it doesn't.

No, and it very easy to check if you call this function:

```
void foo(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a * b));
}
```

> Would the compiler be smart enough to understand what I want?

No, the compiler does not have to predict what you want, it has to follow the instructions written in the C Standard. **You** need to learn and understand the language well enough to know how datatypes will behave in your code.

> I wish I could write this C code without worrying that the ARM
> compiler will create non-optimal code. Am I forced to do this in
> assembly code to make sure it's done right?

Trust your compiler. It will generate a very efficient machine code for **your** program. You need to tell the compiler what you want.

In programming, you should not be tempted to write as short source file as possible, you need to be **precise**. Also, code should be easy to understand for humans.

Also, do not worry about premature optimizations. In 99.99% not efficient code is related to bad algorithm (which is the programmer fault), not poor compiler work.

Example:

```
int64_t foo(int32_t b0, 
        int32_t b1,
        int32_t b2,
        int32_t a1,
        int32_t a2,
        int32_t state_x1,
        int32_t state_x2,
        int32_t state_y1,
        int32_t state_y2,
        int32_t x,
        int64_t accumulator)
{
    accumulator += (int64_t)b0*x;
    accumulator += (int64_t)b1*state_x1;
    accumulator += (int64_t)b2*state_x2;
    accumulator += (int64_t)a1*state_y1;
    accumulator += (int64_t)a2*state_y2;
    return accumulator;
}
```

ARM (Cortex-m 32bit thumb)

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     ip, r1
        mov     lr, r0
        ldrd    r0, r1, [sp, #32]
        ldr     r4, [sp, #28]
        smlal   r0, r1, lr, r4
        ldr     r4, [sp, #12]
        smlal   r0, r1, ip, r4
        ldr     r4, [sp, #16]
        smlal   r0, r1, r2, r4
        ldr     r2, [sp, #20]
        smlal   r0, r1, r3, r2
        ldr     r3, [sp, #24]
        ldr     r2, [sp, #8]
        smlal   r0, r1, r2, r3
        pop     {r4, pc}
```

Comment: Uhm, I've been coding in C since 1982 and have seen soooo many different compilers and optimizer flags that I have forgotten most.  Borland, THINK C, CodeWarrior, whatever.  Also I *have* seen some optimizers anticipate things that might actually impress you.  Casting a 32-bit number to a 64-bit number and then multiplying another 32-bit number immediately after tells the optimizer in the compiler that it need not do a 64 x 64 multiplication.

Comment: But I don't know diddley shit about the ARM compilers and possible optimizers therein.  And I have never written a line of assembly code in any ARM target.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson if you had 40y+ C programming experience you would not ask this question for sure

Comment: Well, as I have said, I have been coding C since I was a grad student at Northwestern and  that was 1981-1985.  I know the C syntax thoroughly which is why I knew that I needed to cast the 32-bit ints into 64 bits before multiplying if I expected to keep all 64 bits of the result.  But compilers and optimizers come and go, and I don't (and cannot) keep up with all of them.  Right now this is heading for some ARM-based target, but it's code deeply nested in and it's gotta be efficient.  I don't want it doing a 64x64->64bit result.  I want it to do a 32x32->64bit result.

Comment: I was hoping that someone might be more familiar with what optimizer options (specifically ARM) might do.  Otherwise, I am going to have to figure out how to do ARM assembly and then I will need to learn about all of the specific differences between the different ARM chips out there.  Right now the assignment is 2nd-order IIR filter in fixed-point with 32-bit registers and make it as efficient as possible.  I was hoping this code could remain as C code so I don't have to learn the asm for whatever ARM chip i'll be dealing with.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You do not have to "keep with compilers" only with the C standard. On two pages you have all integer conversion rules explained. Just keep with it - same as compilers do

Comment: I understand what the rules are.  The code above will work.  But, unoptimized, the code above will waste a bunch of instructions sign-extending a 32-bit signed int into a 64-bit, then it will waste more instructions doing a 64x64->64bit result.  It need only do a 32x32->64bit result.  But I am having trouble coaxing the compiled code into doing that.

Comment: You realize that you misquoted me.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson enable optimizations and compiler will do exactly what you want https://godbolt.org/z/a3EqMG9ao

Comment: All right.  Thank you.  I am going to look into this (I gotta teach myself an asm that I hadn't yet learned).  But this might end up being exactly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Okay, I have reversed my downvote, then upvoted, then accepted this answer.  Other than misquoting me: *//"in C, multiplying an int32_t times an int32_t would implicitly result in an int64_t"//* and refuting the misquote, and initially avoiding the crux of the issue and telling me crap like *//" you need to be **precise**. Also, code should be easy to understand for humans."//*, this answer is ***the answer***.  Thank you *gulpr*.  But I think you initially grossly underestimated my C chops and not until the end actually acted on the question. Thank you for figuring this out, where I cannot.

Answer (score 2):

> this wouldn't be a problem if, in C, multiplying an `int32_t` times an `int32_t` would implicitly result in an `int64_t`. But it doesn't.

You're right, it doesn't, except if your `int` happens to be the same type as `int64_t`, and your implementation also provides `int32_t`.  I don't know any implementation with those characteristics, but there could be one.

> But I don't want to waste the MIPS to multiply an `int64_t` times an `int32_t` when I know that both values are 32-bit numbers

C does not provide a way to express a 32-bit x 32-bit multiplication with a 64-bit result.  Nor do any of the several other statically-typed high-level languages I know.

> I also know that the result must be 64-bits wide else there is trouble.

The result must be (at least) 64 bits wide to avoid any possibility that it overflows.  Whether an overflow can actually occur for any particular multiplication in any particular program is a different question, as is whether an overflow is genuinely troublesome under any particular circumstances.  I do not care to analyze the presented code in this regard so I stipulate that it will produce incorrect results if it does not account for overflow of 32-bit integer multiplications.

> Would the compiler be smart enough to understand what I want? To multiply two 32-bit signed integers together and add the 64-bit result into a 64-bit accumulator without casting anything into a 64-bit register? (i.e. no sign-extension operation and no 64 x 64 bit multiply?)

I take you to be asking about these lines:

> ```
>     accumulator += (int64_t)b0*x;
>     accumulator += (int64_t)b1*state_x1;
>     accumulator += (int64_t)b2*state_x2;
>     accumulator += (int64_t)a1*state_y1;
>     accumulator += (int64_t)a2*state_y2;
> ```

I cannot assure you that a compiler would generate code such as you ask.  In the formal semantics of the language, *both* factors of each of those multiplications are converted to `int64_t` and 64-bit multiplies are performed.  It is plausible, however, that your compiler would recognize that pattern and perform the multiplication as you want.  The chance is much better if you compile with optimizations enabled.

> Am I forced to do this in assembly code to make sure it's done right?

"Done right" is rather opinionated, but yes, if you want absolute certainty that the multiplications are done using a specific sequence of machine instructions that you choose, then that is exactly what assembly is for.

Before you do that, however, I encourage you to test your code to determine whether it needs performance improvement in the first place, and to profile your code to get an idea of what part would benefit most from hand tuning.

Comment: ***Finally***, someone is looking at the specific issue that I am asking about.  Thank you, John.

Comment: *//"The result must be (at least) 64 bits wide to avoid any possibility that it overflows. Whether an overflow can actually occur for any particular multiplication in any particular program is a different question,"//* - - - - So these five coefficients, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2 are all fixed-point values that have mathematical range from -2 to +2 and that the integer representations are 2^30 times bigger.  And I have 2 guard bits to the left.  I don't expect the output signal to be bigger in amplitude than the input.  The `if` statements will clip it just before it's cast back to a 32-bit int.